# Proving there exists an unique endomorphism

Tags: linear-algebra

> Let $V$ a vector space and $\{v_1,v_2, v_3\}$ a basis of $V$. Prove that there exists a unique endomorphism $f:V \to V$ such that
> $$f(v_1) = v_1 + v_2, \quad f(v_3) =v_1, \quad \text{ker}(f)=\text{span}(v_1+v_2).$$

I have deduced that
$$f(v_1 + v_2 + v_3) = f(v_1+v_2) +f(v_3) =f(v_3) =v_1,$$
since $v_1+v_2\in\text{ker}(f)$, and then
$$v_1 = f(v_1 + v_2 + v_3) = f(v_1) +  f(v_2) +f(v_3) = v_1 + v_2 + f(v_2) + v_1,$$
so a matrix of the transformation with respect the given basis should be
$$\begin{pmatrix}
1 & -1 & 1 \\
1 & -1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 
\end{pmatrix}$$
However, I feel this does not prove the question. Can anyone give me a hint? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Your reasoning is perfect and does define $f$ uniquely. In general, a linear map $f$ is completely determined by its action on a basis, so once you know $f(v_1),f(v_2)$ and $f(v_3)$ explicitly, all of $f$ is determined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're basically already done. $f$ is uniquely defined by where it sends basis vectors. Your given where $f$ sends $v_1$ and $v_2$, and you've shown that $\operatorname{ker} f = \operatorname{span}(v_1+v_2)$ implies that $v_1 = v_1 + v_2 + f(v_2)  + v_1 = 2v_1 + v_2 + f(v_2)$. Rearranging gives that $f(v_2) = -v_1 - v_2$. We know how $f$ must act on a basis and so we have completely defined $f$.

Answer (score 1):

The result follows from the fact that $\{v_1,v_2,v_3\}$ is a basis $\implies\{v_1,v_1+v_2,v_1+v_2+v_3\}$ is a basis.  A linear transformation is uniquely determined by its effect on a basis.